# When wifi / data is disabled, saving data

Tags: objective-c, ipad, nsuserdefaults

I'm working on an app where it needs to communicate to a Web Api when it needs to save data. Where would be the best place to save it if wifi/data is not available to send the request? Was thinking NSUSerDefaults, but wasn't sure if this would be the most efficient and secure way?

Let me know your thoughts!

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what kind of data do you want to save? Big one? Does it need to be secured (private infos)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on type and amount of data you want to save. `NSUserDefaults` may suffice for small property lists. In case of large amount of data you can use `NSFileManager` to organise and save your data into files and folders. You may also consider using `Core Data` if your data can be organised into a database. Choose whichever suits your needs.